# How to get value of SharedPreferences android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use `SharedPreferences` here is what i do

```
public void StoreToshared(Object userData){
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(userData);
    Log.d("data", " Setup --> "+json);
    prefsEditor.putString("userinfo", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}
```

`Log.d` result is like this

```
 Setup --> {"nameValuePairs":{"userData":{"nameValuePairs":{"phone":"089688xxxxxxx",
  "username":"username of User","flag":1,"Email":"mymail@mail.com",
  "tipe":"TP001","Deskripsi":"Ini tentang gua","user_id":"USER001",
 "password":"c83e4046a7c5d3c4bf4c292e1e6ec681","fullname":My fullname"}},"status":"true"}}
```

then i'm trying to retrieve it, in other activity here is what i do

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

        String data = mPrefs.getString("userinfo", null);
        Log.i("Text", "Here is the retrieve");
        Log.i("data", " retrieve --> "+data);

    }
```

and here how i open my other activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

With my script above, the result from my `logcat` , i only see like `Log.d` above. So my question is, how can i retrieve it ?

Comment: What's wrong in this code now. can't you get data or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a key on your `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void StoreToshared(Object userData){
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("your_sp_key", MODE_PRIVATE); //add key
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(userData);
    Log.d("data", " Setup --> "+json);
    prefsEditor.putString("userinfo", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}
```

Retrieval:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("your_sp_key", MODE_PRIVATE); //add key
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    String data = mPrefs.getString("userinfo", null);
    Log.i("Text", "Here is the retrieve");
    Log.i("data", " retrieve --> "+data);

}
```

Comment: i get this error `Error:(72, 36) error: method getPreferences in class Activity cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: I've updated my code, it seems that there's getPreferences, and there's getSharedPreferences. use getSharedPreferences and try it again. Thank you.

Comment: How can i get this only   `"username":"username of User"` and set it to variable ?

Comment: That's another question, please refer to the gson.fromGson(), try to refer to this link: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: You don't need the SharedPreferences.Editor for the retrieval

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 method:

```
// put value
public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and

```
// get value
public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}
```

then you can put value

```
putPref("userinfo", "/** user data json */", getApplicationContext());
```

and get value

```
String data = getPref("userinfo", getApplicationContext());
```

I hope it can help your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string data from `SharedPreferences` back to a PoJo using Gson. Simply do this:

```
Object userData = new Gson().fromJson(data, Object.class);
```

I guess that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The api: getPreferences will use the activity name to create an xml file if not exists. For example, assume StoreToshared method is put in activity: LoginActivity.java, it will create a file: LoginActivity.xml to store your pref data. Hence, when you go into other activity, let say its name is: MainActivity.java, getPreferences will look into file "MainActivity.xml" instead of "LoginActivity.xml", that is why you cannot retrieve your data.

The solution is to use: getSharedPreferences.
Hence your code can be modified as follow:

public void StoreToshared(Object userData) {

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(userData);
Log.d("data", " Setup --> "+json);
prefsEditor.putString("userinfo", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    String data = mPrefs.getString("userinfo", null);
    Log.i("Text", "Here is the retrieve");
    Log.i("data", " retrieve --> "+data);

}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In year 2020,
Google has been released new data storage that is repleced of Shared Preference...
It' is developed with "Kotlin"

[Source](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore)