# How to show a alert dialog when app is launched first time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have two audio files in my app. When the app is launched the first time and when the user plays the first audio for the first time, I want to show a dialog, but afterwards never show it again.

When the user clicks OK, then only the dialog will disappear.

I have only created the XML of the dialog because I don't know how to show a layout when the app is launched the first time.

**MainActivity.java**  here the player1 (Media Player) and play1 (ImageView as the button to play the audio) is for the first audio where the dialog has to be shown.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player1, player2;
    SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2;
    TextView currentTime1, currentTime2;
    TextView remainingTime1, remainingTime2;
    ImageView play1, play2;
    int totalTime1, totalTime2;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // PlayButton    *  The ButtonClick is in the last if you want to jump directly there  *

        play1 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
        play2 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn2);

        // TimeLables

        currentTime1 = findViewById(R.id.currentTime1);
        currentTime2 = findViewById(R.id.currentTime2);
        remainingTime1 = findViewById(R.id.totalTime1);
        remainingTime2 = findViewById(R.id.totalTime2);

        // MediaPlayer

        player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_howl);
        player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_bark);
        player1.setLooping(false);
        player1.seekTo(0);
        totalTime1 = player1.getDuration();
        player2.setLooping(false);
        player2.seekTo(0);
        totalTime2 = player2.getDuration();


        //SeekBar

        seekBar1 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekBar2 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar2);
        seekBar1.setMax(totalTime1);
        seekBar2.setMax(totalTime2);

        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                player1.seekTo(progress);
                seekBar1.setProgress(progress);
                currentTime1.setText(createTimerLable1(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                player2.seekTo(i);
                seekBar2.setProgress(i);
                currentTime2.setText(createTimerLable2(i));


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });


        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player1 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player1.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler1.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player2 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player2.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler2.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();


        // Admob Banner Ad

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler1 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition1 = msg.what;
            //Update SeekBar
            seekBar1.setProgress(currentPosition1);
            // Update Timelable
            String totTime1 = createTimerLable1(player1.getDuration());
            remainingTime1.setText(totTime1);

        }
    };
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition2 = msg.what;
            // Update SeekBar
            seekBar2.setProgress(currentPosition2);
            // Update Timelable
            String totTime2 = createTimerLable2(player2.getDuration());
            remainingTime2.setText(totTime2);

        }
    };

    public String createTimerLable1(int duration) {
        String timerLabel = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel += "0";
        timerLabel += sec;
        return timerLabel;


    }

    public String createTimerLable2(int duration) {
        String timerLabel = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel += "0";
        timerLabel += sec;
        return timerLabel;


    }

    public void playBtnClick1(View view) {

        if (player2.isPlaying()) {
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player1.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player1.start();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

    public void playBtnClick2(View view) {

        if (player1.isPlaying()) {
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player2.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player2.start();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You will put the info that you played the video in shared preferences.

Comment: can you provide some reference , it will be helpful (preferred StackOverflow questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @blackapps suggested, You will save the information about the user in `SharedPreferences`. You will save whether you have displayed the dialog and whether user's has played audio for first time or not.

To save or get the details from SharedPreferences,

1. You can follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502598/8641169) for storing strings, int, boolean etc.
2. You can follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463758/8641169) for storing custom objects.