# Retrieving data using shared preferences

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Can i retrieve shared Preferences of single String data in another class of which having a   `recyclerView`of **ArrayList**

I have a save button in activity which will save the date And time , date and time specified in the app itself and I want to retrieve the same data in another activity which having a `recyclerView`of **ArrayList** .

Save button will only save the data and there is another button through which i will go to the another activity

```
public class StudentListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter rAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<ListOfNames> listOfNames;


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

String t1 = "10";
String t2 = "100%";
Bundle bundle;
String subName;
Toolbar toolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    subName = bundle.getString("Subject Name");
    if (bundle != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(subName);
    }
    loadData();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());


    toolbar.setSubtitle(currentDate);
    fabButton();
    buildRecyclerView();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScrollingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("count", listOfNames.size());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            handleDate();

            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PastAttendences.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        case R.id.title3:
```

// i want to use sharedPrefrences here to save the date/time

```
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void handelTime(final CharSequence charSequence) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int Hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int Minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    boolean is24Hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int Hour, int Minute) {


            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, Hour);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);

            CharSequence charSequence1 = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("HH.mm", calendar1);
            toolbar.setSubtitle(charSequence + " " + charSequence1);
        }
    }, Hour, Minute, is24Hour);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

public void handleDate() {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int date) {


            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

            CharSequence charSequence = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MMM-yyyy", calendar1);

            handelTime(charSequence);
        }
    }, year, month, date);

    datePickerDialog.show();
}


private void buildRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(StudentListActivity.this);
    rAdapter = new AdapterForStudentList(listOfNames);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

public void insertData(String text, String t1, String t2) {
    ListOfNames lt = new ListOfNames(text, t1, t2);
    listOfNames.add(lt);
    rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void saveData() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(listOfNames);
    editor.putString(subName, json);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadData() {


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(subName, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListOfNames>>() {
    }.getType();

    listOfNames = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (listOfNames == null) {
        listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

ListOfNames deletedItem = null;
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String name = listOfNames.get(position).getStudentName();

        deletedItem = listOfNames.get(position);
        listOfNames.remove(deletedItem);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("text");


        saveData();
        editor.apply();
        rAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, name + "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        listOfNames.add(position, deletedItem);
                        rAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

                        saveData();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(StudentListActivity.this, R.color.my_background))
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                .create()
                .decorate();
        super.onChildDrawOver(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

    }
};

public void fabButton() {
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentListActivity.this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogbox_frontpage, null);

            final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            b.setView(view);
            b.setTitle("Student name");
            b.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();

                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(StudentListActivity.this, "Please add subject name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        insertData(text, t1, t2);
                        saveData();
                    }
                }
            });
            b.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Next Activity**

```
public class PastAttendences extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

ArrayList<ListOfPastAttendences> mItems;
public static final String DATETIME = "dateTime";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.past_attendence);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.attendenceToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Past Attendances");


    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    buildRecyclerView();

}


public void buildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.pARecyclerView);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new PastAttendenceAdapter(mItems);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to save an arraylist in sharedpreferences ?

Comment: No i have a single string value in a activity which i want to update in another activity of recyclerView having a ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can Intiate sharedPref(as shown in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) :-

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

U can get sharedpref by using(as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001112/12987677):-

```
      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      preferences.getString(key, null);
```

You can store Array as String

```
editor.putString(key,Array.toString());
editor.apply();
```

You can get the Array from string (some code below is in kotlin syntax)

```
variableOne =JSONArray(preferences.getString(key, null));
VariableThreeList = ArrayList()
 for (i in 0 until variableOne !!.length()) {
             variableTwo = JSONObject(variableOne !![i].toString())
            VariableThreeList!!.add(variableTwo.getString("Name"))
           }
        }
```

note: JSONArray, JSONObject is from import org.json.JSONArray, import org.json.JSONObject

Comment: i want to set the data in array list but how can i do that

Comment: idk about that, i use kotlin and i haven't come across the problem of setting data in array list. sorry i answered the initial problem though.

Comment: its fine i used shared prefrences in my app many times but this time the thing is diffrerent ..

Comment: @Kaunain I hope the edited version is the answer you were looking for